# Retrieve list status from sub sites using SharePoint Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I'm creating a status page in the site collection that needs to display List Status of all the subs below site collection. All the sub-sites have the same list 'Projects'. So the idea is to iterate all subwebs and report on the list in a tabular format. 
When I don't call function 'retrieveListItemsInclude()' then all the sub-sites are listed, when I do call the function an alert box appears but execution halts after 1st iteration. The function doesn't seem to return.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(RetrieveSites,"sp.js");

function RetrieveSites()
 {
    currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    currentweb = currentcontext.get_web();
    //this.subsites = currentweb.get_webs();
    this.subsites = currentweb.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
    currentcontext.load(this.subsites);
    currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.SitesExecuteOnSuccess),Function.createDelegate(this, this.SitesExecuteOnFailure));
 }


function SitesExecuteOnSuccess(sender, args) 
 {
//var HTMLContent = '';
var enum1 = this.subsites.getEnumerator();
el = document.getElementById('LKMSubWebs');

var HTMLContent;

while (enum1.moveNext())
{
var Site = enum1.get_current();
//alert('hi123');
//Add Subsites to HTML Content
HTMLContent += '\n' + '<img title="css" alt="css" src="/_layouts/15/images/SharePointFoundation16.png" border="0">&nbsp;' + '<a class=subsitecls href='+ Site.get_serverRelativeUrl()+'>'+Site.get_title()+'</a> </br>';
//RootElement.append('<a class=subsitecls href='+ siteTitle+'>'+siteTitle+'</a> </br>');
   }
//set div to content
el.innerHTML = HTMLContent;
 retrieveListItemsInclude();

 }
 function SitesExecuteOnFailure(sender, args) 
 {
alert("error");
//alert(args.get_message());
 }




function retrieveListItemsInclude() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();//(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Project');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Id, DisplayName, HasUniqueRoleAssignments)');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nDisplay name: ' + oListItem.get_displayName() + 
            '\nUnique role assignments: ' + oListItem.get_hasUniqueRoleAssignments();
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right general idea but the way you compose your calls can be improved a lot by grouping all of the loading into a single collection of objects before executing the async request to load the list item objects one time.

I started my answer below while working on another question you asked so I ditched a lot of your code unfortunately but it should give you somewhere to start and plug in your html generation logic. The following should log the "first" item title that is retrieved from every "Projects" list within the site collection to the console.

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    var myCtx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var root = myCtx.get_site().get_rootWeb(); // may need to do this if in a sub site
    var webs = root.get_webs(); // fetch a reference to all the sub webs
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    // only need to fetch the first item returned from each Project list
    query.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
    var queryItemCollections = [];
    // make sure to load the lists data so we can check
    // if the "Projects" list exists in each site
    myCtx.load(webs, "Include(Id, Lists)");
    myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        // push new SP.ListItemCollections into an array and tell the ctx to fetch them
        for (var i = 0; i < webs.get_data().length; i++) {
            var web = webs.get_data()[i], itms;
            if (checkForProjectsList(web)) {
                itms = webs.get_data()[i].get_lists()
                           .getByTitle("Projects").getItems(query);
                queryItemCollections.push(itms);
                myCtx.load(itms);
            }
        }
        myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            if (queryItemCollections.length == 0) {
                console.log("collection empty");
            }
            queryItemCollections.forEach(function (item) {
                // do work with individual list items here
                console.log(item.getItemAtIndex(0).get_item("Title"));
            });
        }, genericFailHandler);
    }, genericFailHandler);
    function checkForProjectsList(web) {
        var lists = web.get_lists().get_data();
        for (var j = 0; j < lists.length; j++) {
            var list = lists[j];
            if (list.get_title() == "Projects") {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    function genericFailHandler(sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    }
}, "SP.js");
```

If you need a different sort order you can modify the `query` object's `viewXml`

You can do more stuff to make this actually production ready, but this should demonstrate a basic approach. Something to note, this won't retrieve any projects from the root web if you also store more projects there, you would have to load that information and include it within the `queryItemCollections` if necessary.

Comment: This works- a few questions if you don't mind :)
Sometimes the 'Project' list does not exist, so code errors, how can this be prevented?

I also need to log 'Status' from the list column however sometimes this is empty, how can code continue when empty?

In my code I started off with 'ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(RetrieveSites,"sp.js");' but you started the code with 'SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {' whats the difference?

Comment: Sorry in the above 'Status' is a dropdown column that exists in Project list

Comment: This will already check if there is no "Project" list in a sub-web before trying to load it, if you have some site collections where there are no project lists add an `if` guard around `myCtx.executeQueryAsync(...)` so that it only executes if 1 or more Project lists was found... To get the `Status` column you should add a line right below where I have the `console.log` statement, you'll want to use `item.getItemAtIndex(0).get_item("Status")` -- I'll leave it to you to figure out how you handle it when that field doesn't have anything (I forget if it is `null` or equal to the empty string)

Comment: 'SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` is the same thing as `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` - there are some members of `SP.SOD` that are not aliased to the `window` object like that though, so I just use the `SP.SOD` namespace so I don't have to remember which is which.

Comment: if the field name is `StatusProject` try changing `myCtx.load(itms);` to `myCtx.load(itms, "Include(Title,StatusProject)");` -- you'll need to enumerate the name of all the fields you want to access there... and double check the field's real name is `StatusProject` in your list properties

Comment: I haven't seen code in the way you supplied, and cant find any examples like this on MS site. How did you create it, have you used intellisence and SPD?

Comment: What's the purpose of creating an array ? does it avoid calling asynchronous functions within a loop ?

Comment: I had named the columns differently in some subs :( that's why

Comment: I store the items in an array so when I load all of their data I can access them easily after loading. In general I really try to avoid making async calls in a loop, but you should almost never need to call `executeQueryAsync` that way since you can just load all of the items in a loop then make a single call afterward. I do most of my SharePoint JavaScript work in TypeScript using Visual Studio Code or the Monaco editor hooked up to a Microsoft Azure Web App unless I'm working on an Addin, then I'll break out Visual Studio. The techniques are just things I've picked up over the years ;)

Comment: @John-M What is the difference between TypeScript and JS? Why go the TS route if you already have JS? Just curious since I see you using Typescript a lot :) And now that techniques like Angular, Knockout are getting more traction, I almost never see the mention of TS anywhere? Does it offer a performance benefit?

Comment: @Akhoy Typescript is a typed (hah!) superset of JavaScript that compiles down to idiomatic JavaScript, I use it because it provides development-time type checking and enables a full intellisense experience with the SharePoint APIs (which is great since they're huge) -- Typescript helps write JavaScript that you can confidently compose an application out of instead of worrying about your scripts breaking each other all the time; I was skeptical at first because it seems like just one more thing to learn but it's amazing: check out the vid on the main page http://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: Hi I'm trying to display the url of the site that the list item is residing in but cant achieve it, could you kindly suggest how ? I've tried outputting site url at the point where you have commented 'do work with individual list items here
' . I started a new thread on this. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/161212/get-site-url-from-list-item-sharepoint-2010-javascript?noredirect=1#comment166163_161212