# Get site url from list item sharepoint 2010 javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I have the following code and need to obtain the site url to form a hyperlink. How can this be achieved?

Code prints out title but I cant get to the web url . I want the url of the site that the list item is within. i.e. 'mysite.com/sites/site-collection/this-sub-site'

```
 myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () {

        // push new SP.ListItemCollections into an array and tell the ctx to fetch them
        for (var i = 0; i < webs.get_data().length; i++) {
            var web = webs.get_data()[i], itms;
            if (checkForProjectsList(web)) {
                itms = webs.get_data()[i].get_lists()
                           .getByTitle("Project").getItems(query);
                queryItemCollections.push(itms);
                myCtx.load(itms);


            }
        }


myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () {

    queryItemCollections.forEach(function (item) {

    console.log(item.getItemAtIndex(0).get_item("Title"));
```

UPDATE ::

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        var myCtx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var root = myCtx.get_site().get_rootWeb(); // may need to do this if in a sub site
        var webs = root.get_webs(); // fetch a reference to all the sub webs
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        // only need to fetch the first item returned from each Project list
        query.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
        var queryItemCollections = [];
        var querySite = [];

        // make sure to load the lists data so we can check
        // if the "Projects" list exists in each site
        myCtx.load(webs, "Include(Id, Lists, Title, ServerRelativeUrl)");
        //  myCtx.load(webs, "Include(Id, Lists, Title, Url)"); // not working


         myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () {

            // push new SP.ListItemCollections into an array and tell the ctx to fetch them
            for (var i = 0; i < webs.get_data().length; i++) {
                var web = webs.get_data()[i], itms;
                if (checkForProjectsList(web)) {
                    itms = webs.get_data()[i].get_lists()
                               .getByTitle("Project").getItems(query);
                    queryItemCollections.push(itms);
                    querySite.push(web.get_serverRelativeUrl());
                    //querySite.push(web.get_url());
                    myCtx.load(itms);
                    console.log(itms);


                    //console.log(web.get_title());
                    console.log(web.get_serverRelativeUrl());

                }
            }


            myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                if (queryItemCollections.length == 0) {
                    console.log("collection empty");
                }


                var k=0;
                queryItemCollections.forEach(function (item) {
                    // do work with individual list items here
                   // console.log(item.getItemAtIndex(0).get_item("Title"));

                   var oProj=item.getItemAtIndex(0).get_item("ProjectRef");

                   var oTitle=item.getItemAtIndex(0).get_item("Title");


                //  $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [ oProj,oProj ] );


                    console.log(querySite[k]);
                    k++;            
    $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [ oProj,oTitle, '' ] );


                    });


            }, genericFailHandler);


        }, genericFailHandler);


        function checkForProjectsList(web) {
            var lists = web.get_lists().get_data();
            for (var j = 0; j < lists.length; j++) {
                var list = lists[j];
                if (list.get_title() == "Project") {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        function genericFailHandler(sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        }

    }, "SP.js");



    </script>



    <table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"  class="display" id="example">
    <thead><tr >
    <th style="text-align:left;">ACE</th>
    <th style="text-align:left;">BASE</th>
    <th style="text-align:left;">BASE</th>


    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

    </table>




    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#example').dataTable( {    
        paging: false,
        searching: false

        } );


    </script>
```

Comment: Which URL you want to obtain?

Comment: url of the web within collection as it loops

Comment: url of the web is that url in your list item collection??

Comment: I think yes, not sure what you mean. I'll update question with more code

Comment: Did you mean the display url of the Item?

Comment: I want the url of the site that the list item is within. i.e. 'mysite.com/sites/site-collection/this-sub-site'

Comment: still confused! Update your question and code

Comment: It seems like you want the URL for the sub-site that contains the list item you load in the code (the URL for `web` within the `for` loop?)

Comment: That's correct John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to get the information from the web object in your loop and somehow store it for use later:

You access `web` object URLs in the JavaScript Object Model with `web.get_url()`. You could put them in an array separate from your web collections or in some kind of object structure that keeps them together -- mostly a matter of what is convenient for you.

One note, since I'm familiar with the code you're talking about, make sure that you include `Url` in the `ctx.load` statement for the web objects.

Here is an entire working snippet:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    var myCtx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var root = myCtx.get_site().get_rootWeb(); // may need to do this if in a sub site
    var webs = root.get_webs(); // fetch a reference to all the sub webs
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    // only need to fetch the first item returned from each Project list
    query.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
    var queryItemCollections = [];
    // make sure to load the lists data so we can check
    // if the "Projects" list exists in each site
    // ** note the load for Url **
    myCtx.load(webs, "Include(Id, Lists, ServerRelativeUrl)");
    myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        // push new SP.ListItemCollections into an array and tell the ctx to fetch them
        for (var i = 0; i < webs.get_data().length; i++) {
            var web = webs.get_data()[i], itms;
            if (checkForProjectsList(web)) {
                console.log("url: " + web.get_serverRelativeUrl());
                itms = webs.get_data()[i].get_lists()
                           .getByTitle("Projects").getItems(query);
                queryItemCollections.push(itms);
                myCtx.load(itms);
            }
        }
        myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            if (queryItemCollections.length == 0) {
                console.log("collection empty");
            }
            queryItemCollections.forEach(function (item) {
                // do work with individual list items here
                console.log(item.getItemAtIndex(0).get_item("Title"));
            });
        }, genericFailHandler);
    }, genericFailHandler);
    function checkForProjectsList(web) {
        var lists = web.get_lists().get_data();
        for (var j = 0; j < lists.length; j++) {
            var list = lists[j];
            if (list.get_title() == "Projects") {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    function genericFailHandler(sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    }
}, "SP.js");
```

Comment: Added   myCtx.load(webs, "Include(Id, Lists, Title, ServerRelativeUrl)");
this gives relative, so tried:
myCtx.load(webs, "Include(Id, Lists, Title, Url)");
now console reports 'Field or property "Url" does not exist.'

Comment: Tried the new code, thanks but still get same error 'Field or property "Url" does not exist.' weird?

Comment: Yep that works, For the last bit where I need to report all data from one place in the section where I also report on list info :  queryItemCollections.forEach(function (item) {..... I created another array, which ties in with the 1st loop  for (var i = 0 ...
I've update the original question, is this robust enough?

Comment: As long as you call the same index in each array it should provide what you're looking for